# libc6 broken: wrong version

Tags: dpkg

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc6-dev:amd64:
 libc6-dev:amd64 depends on libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.3); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.19-0ubuntu6.1.
```

How do I fix my libc6? I've done `sudo apt-get update`, `fix-missing`, `install -f`. None is working.

Comment: Yes, I've tried those. I don't think this is so much as broken, but just the wrong version. Most of these fix won't work I think because the file is okay. Just the wrong version but there's no fix to fixing wrong versions. I've tried that link but so far no success. Thanks!

Comment: What does your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file look like (that is, what is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`). Also, what's the output of `lsb_release -a` and `uname -a`? I wonder if you might have some software sources enabled that are wrong for your system (or if you might need to enable some that are right for your system but currently not being used). The best way to provide all this information is with an [edit] (especially long terminal output--you can paste it into your question, select it, and use Ctrl+K to format it as code so it's easily readable).

Comment: Also, did you try other techniques at [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/22949) besides running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get -f install`? The many answers there provides various methods--even if some or most don't work for you, one or more others still may. So in addition to the information requested above, please also [edit] a detailed description of everything you've tried, and exactly what happened when you did. Right now it's not clear what your problem is or how it's different from [that one](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/22949). Thanks!

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy libc6-dev:amd64 libc6:amd64`?